# О названии марки автомобиля

Tags: фонетика, ономастика

Как правильно по-русски называть автомобиль Porsche? Я слышал варианты и "П**о**рше", и "Порш**е**", и "Порш". По идее, автомобиль назван в честь его разработчика, немецкого конструктора Фердинанда П**о**рше. Значит, выходит, так говорить правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно так, как вы и предполагаете: п**о**рше, нескл., мужского рода (автомобиль).